# Julia 0.6 to Postgres connection - Available options and LibPq.jl

Tags: postgresql, julia, libpq

I was with Julia 0.5 and used [PostgreSql.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/PostgreSQL.jl) to connect to the Database.  It internally uses DBI.jl dependency.

Now upgrading to version 0.6, this has stopped working.  The only alternative I could find online is [LibPQ.jl](https://github.com/invenia/LibPQ.jl).  However, the library is a huge inconvenience to use.

Does anyone here have experience with connecting to Postgres from Julia?  How did you achieve it?

Please shoot any questions if I have missed giving any information.

Answer (score 3):

I achieved it by writing and using PostgreSQL.jl, and later LibPQ.jl. PostgreSQL.jl was very much a novice effort, and I stand by LibPQ.jl as the better option. Briefly in development we used ODBC.jl, but found that difficult to configure, inflexible in output, and slow. Using LibPQ.jl has simplified our database interaction code and improved transfer speeds.

I found it more useful to write a package that supported an existing general data interface (DataStreams.jl) than to write and maintain a database interface that I wasn't personally invested in. There's certainly opportunity to do so, and to support the interface using LibPQ.jl, but it is no longer a personal goal of mine.

I am also happy to discuss any inconvenience you have using LibPQ.jl in an appropriate forum (tagging me on the JuliaLang Discourse site always gets a response).

Comment: thx @iamed2! You was big contributor to [dbapi.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/DBAPI.jl/graphs/contributors) too. It is also abandoned now?

Comment: Thanks @iamed2.  Would love to discuss and contribute to the library.

Comment: @Liso yes the code currently there is abandoned, but there is interest in resurrecting a database interface effort and that seems to be moving forward now, on Discourse and in the DBAPI.jl issues

Comment: @Sid feel free to message me on Slack, tag me in a post on Discourse, or file issues on LibPQ.jl :)